# Is the proof below correct?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is bounded from above by $N$. Show that if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$, then $L \leq N$.

As $L$ is the limit of $f$ as $x \to c$ then for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that
                 $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$
whenever $|x - c| < \delta$.
Now let us suppose that $L > N$, then there exists a positive number $k$ such that $L = N + k$
Then 
 $L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$ implies 
$N < f(x) < L + \epsilon$ if we choose $\epsilon = k$.
But this is a contradiction as $f$ is bounded from above by $N$. So $L \leq N$.

Comment: Correct. (But perhaps more lengthy then needed - "Suppose $L>N$. Then $\epsilon:=L-N$ is positive, hence there exists $\delta$ such that ..." - then again, longer is better than too short and omitting something important)

Comment: Yes, it's important to always make it clear that $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$. I like your way of arguing in rough, but Hagen's way is how you should write up your final draft for submission